# Get meaningful information when fopen() fails (PHP/suPHP)

Tags: php, file, error-handling, suphp

How do I get something more meaningful than 'FALSE' when I can't open a file.

```
$myFile = "/home/user/testFile.txt"; 
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

When I use the `die` statement, `can't open file` is returned to the client, and it is almost useless. If I remove it, no error is raised. If I return `$fh` it is `FALSE`. I tried both local file name and absolute file name. My `index.html` file is in one of the sub folders of my hole folder. Furthermore, I am using suPHP with the folder I am trying to write to having a permission of `0755` (suPHP requires this for all folders).

How do I figure out why there was a problem, or at least query it before trying to open the file.

Comment: Turn on error reporting?

Comment: I totally forgot about that. At the top of my page I have it set to `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` Is that sufficient?

Comment: IIRC it is unless displaying errors is turned off in php.ini.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fopen` should raise an E_WARNING if it fails. See [error_get_last](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) or [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)(*) to catch it. Other than that you can use [file_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [is_readable](http://www.php.net/is_readable) to check whether the file is missing or there's another (probably permission-related) problem.

(*) I consider it good practice to always set an error handler that turns all PHP errors into exceptions.

Comment: Is there a proper way to propagate exceptions back to the client? Right now I am just printing/echoing these.

Comment: @puk: That's depends how you design your application. It can be just fitting to give back a message, some want to display javascript popups, others want to display an error page and so on and so forth. I think the most important part first is, that you have one useful error message for the user, and one technically insightful error message for the developer, e.g. into an application error log.

Comment: would this error be displayed client side, serverside, or does it depend on 'how you design your application'?

Comment: You choose where and how you want to show your errors. Often people show a generic "something went wrong" to the user (except in development mode) and log and/or e-mail the actual error. But don't overcomplicate things prematurely :)

Answer (score 12):

Use error_get_last() to catch the (supressed) errors in php:

```
$f = @fopen("x", "r") or die(print_r(error_get_last(),true));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the '@' here, I have never seen that before.

Comment: @puk @ symbol is the error control operator. It suppresses any errors emitted by that function. In the end, this means that if the function fails, you won’t see any errors related to it on screen or in your logs. This is a poor practice and should be avoided. You can always set a custom error handler to catch errors.